# Trying to set the opacity of an image by clicking on it using javascript but keep getting an error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the opacity of an image by clicking on it using javascript but keep getting the following error (Also I'm new to Javascript):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of
>   null at HTMLDivElement.thumbnails.(anonymous function).onclick

```js
let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById(thumbnails[i]).getElementsByTagName('img').style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your remaining code??

Comment: Add ur html or its portion

Answer (score 1):

You already have reference to the thumbnail element so there is no need to get it by id. You want something like this:

```js
let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
  thumbnails[i].onclick = function() {
    thumbnails[i].querySelector('img').style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div>
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div><div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></div>
```

Comment: This answer is the best fit imo.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to make the image fully opaque? Whenever I try setting it equal to 1 it doesn't change.

Comment: They start off fully opaque in my example which is why I set it to 0.5 on click to show a difference. You can just swap it around so they are styled to be slightly transparent with CSS and then are set to be opaque in JS.

Answer (score 0):

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
 returns an array-like NodeList

You cant use getElementsByTagName, you probably want to iterate that array and find the children in each element. For that you need to use a queryselector again.

Answer (score 0):

The `thumbnails[i]` is already an Element no need to `getElementById`,
So considering you already have you parent element go for it's child using `firstElementChild`

```js
let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
  thumbnails[i].onclick = function() {
    thumbnails[i].firstElementChild.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/GszSyNI.jpg" style="width:60px; opacity: .4"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/GszSyNI.jpg" style="width:60px; opacity: .2"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/GszSyNI.jpg" style="width:60px; opacity: .1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.thumbnail` is the class of a parent element of your image:

```js
let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail img");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
  thumbnails[i].onclick = function() {
    this.style.opacity = .5;
  }
}
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />

</div>
```

Comment: clearly `thumbnail` is the class of parent element of the image

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a variable `thumbnails[i]` to method `document.getElementByID`
Secondly `getElementsByTagName` return collection of elements. If there is only 1 img in your .thumbnail then use `querySelector('img')` if more then loop through whole array.
Here is example considering only 1 `img` in `.thumbnail`

```
let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].onclick = function () {
        thumbnail[i].querySelector('img').style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```